# Replace an element into a specific position of a vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, stl, insert

I want to replace an element into a specific position of a vector, can I just use an assignment:

```
// vec1 and 2 have the same length & filled in somehow
vec1;
vec2;

vec1[i] = vec2[i] // insert vec2[i] at position i of vec1
```

or I have to use insert():

```
vector<sometype>::iterator iterator = vec1.begin();

vec1.insert(iterator+(i+1), vec2[i]);
```

Comment: Be careful of your phrasing here. `Insert` will mean adding an element at a location and moving all subsequent elements up one place in the vector (ie growing the vector by one element). On the other hand you can use `setting` to indicate you want to change an existing vector element to a new value.

Comment: i think what i want is to replace whatever at vec1[i] with vec2[i]; and in my case vec[i] can be null, and i want to keep the lengths of vec1 and 2 the same;

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
vec1[i] = vec2[i]
```

will set the value of `vec1[i]` to the value of `vec2[i]`. Nothing is inserted. Your second approach is almost correct. Instead of `+i+1` you need just `+i`

```
v1.insert(v1.begin()+i, v2[i])
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do that using [at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/). You can try out the following simple example:

```
const size_t N = 20;
std::vector<int> vec(N);
try {
    vec.at(N - 1) = 7;
} catch (std::out_of_range ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
assert(vec.at(N - 1) == 7);
```

Notice that method `at` returns an `allocator_type::reference`, which is that case is a `int&`. Using `at` is equivalent to assigning values like `vec[i]=...`.

---

There is a difference between `at` and [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) as it can be understood with the following example:

```
const size_t N = 8;
std::vector<int> vec(N);
for (size_t i = 0; i<5; i++){
    vec[i] = i + 1;
}

vec.insert(vec.begin()+2, 10);
```

If we now print out `vec` we will get:

```
1 2 10 3 4 5 0 0 0
```

If, instead, we did `vec.at(2) = 10`, or `vec[2]=10`, we would get

```
1 2 10 4 5 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

See an example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/
eg.:

```
...
vector::iterator iterator1;

  iterator1= vec1.begin();
  vec1.insert ( iterator1+i , vec2[i] );

// This means that at position "i" from the beginning it will insert the value from vec2 from position i
```

Your first approach was replacing the values from vec1[i] with the values from vec2[i]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `std::vector::insert` if you want to use reserved memory and don't want to change the size of your buffer, try to use memcpy instead as below:

```cpp
auto begin = static_cast<const uint8_t*>(data);
memcpy(&data_buffer[write_pos], begin, size);
```