# Inserting an specific item in a Vector

Tags: c++, oop, vector, getter-setter

I'm new to C++ and I am having problems adapting from Java. I know that Vectors in C++ work similar to ArrayList in Java, but I am having some problems understanding it completely.

Let's say I have a `vector<PetStore*> pets`, and each `PetStore` object has some getters and setters. I want to set/insert a specific element at a specific index in the vector. I also want to call the method `bool setAdopted(bool adopted)` on the inserted pet and set adopted to `true`.

```
/*
     Pseudo code
     pets.insert(pets.begin()+i, setAdopted(true));
*/
```

Comment: I cant understand your example but here is an example about how to insert for vector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726805/insert-an-element-into-a-specific-position-of-a-vector

Comment: Try this: `pets[specific_index].setadopted(true);`

Comment: @Thomas I saw that earlier, but I'm working with OOP.

Comment: @ruhul Thanks, but it didn't work.

Comment: Show how you would do this in Java. As it currently stands, you have not shown any evidence of an attempt apart from the pseudo code which I recognize as neither Java nor C++

Comment: As you changed to  pointer type later, try `pets[specific_index]->setadopted(true);` or `pets.at(specific_index)->setadopted(true);`  instead of `pets[specific_index].setadopted(true);` ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to set/insert a specific element at a specific index

Insert

```
PetStore *item;
item = new PetStore();
vector<PetStore*> pets;
vector<PetStore*>::iterator it;
it = pets.begin();
it = pets.insert ( it , item );
// another way.. 
pets.insert (it,2,item);
```

Set:

```
pets.at(indx)->setadopted(true);
```

Links: [vector/insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)

Comment: Assuming `PetStore` is defined as a pointer type, then your answer will be correct

Comment: Thanks! It finally compiled