# Converting an array of int, to a vector of int in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have an array something like this

```
int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
vector<int> vec;
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
if(some condition) {
    index = i;
}
**vec(A + index, i);**
}
```

how to convert an array to vector starting from particular index, like above ?

Comment: Why can't you just use `vec.push_back()` and fill up vector that way?
If you want to copy entire array int vector:
`for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)`
  `vec.push_back(A[i]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `index` as follows.

```
#include <iterator>

int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
if( /* some condition */ ) {
    index = i;
    break;
}

}
std::vector<int> vec ( std::begin(A) + index, std::end(A) ) ;
```

Comment: Showoff ;-). Don't forget to `#include` the header for `std::begin`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Not really needed.  It is guaranteed to be included with vector and the OP should already be including that since they are using a vector.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<int> vec(A + index, A + sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]));` is the way the cool cats do it.

Answer (score -2):

As I have seen in the internet you can add elements to the vectors using insert method, you can get all the elements of your array and adding them to the vector with the for loop just like the following code:

```
int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
vector<int> vec;
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
if(some condition) {
    vec.insert(vec.begin()+index,A[i]));
    index++;
}
**vec(A + index, i);**
}
```

See this post for more information

[insert an element into a specific position of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726805/insert-an-element-into-a-specific-position-of-a-vector)

Comment: `insert` is for inserting an element at a certain position. when starting with an empty vector using `push_back` makes more sense

Comment: What's `A.size()`? Missing semi-colon on the first line, wrong no. of brackets at `vec.insert()` <- which should as pointed out should really just be `emplace_back()` or  `push_back()` or at the very least construct the vector with a size , and what is `**vec(A + index, i);**`?

Comment: @George I just reused the code of the author so he can see what differences I made on his code. The **vec(A + index, i);** should be a comment.

Comment: @BrankVictoria The main reason I dv'd was that the answer you gave is incorrect even if the op's code were correct. Plus giving back broken code is not a good way to answer a question. If you edit the answer, i'll take my dv off.