# Is there a way to repeatedly insert an element at a specific position to a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I know my question seems very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726805/insert-an-element-into-a-specific-position-of-a-vector), but the solutions provided there don't work in this case.

What I'm trying to do is very simple, put an element to a specific position in a vector.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(2);

    vec.insert(vec.begin() + 0, 0);
    vec.insert(vec.begin() + 0, 1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
    std::cout << vec.at(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

The output is

```
1
0
```

But I want the output to be just `1`.

The second time I `insert`, the element is inserted at the `0th` position and the element previously at `0th` moves to `1st` position. I want the second call to `insert` have the same exact effect as the first call i.e. insert element to 0th position. In other words, I want the second call of `insert` to substitute the value at `0th` position. How do I do this?

CLARIFICATION:

My code included in this question is a short example of what I want. I'm calling `insert` twice but the first argument to `insert` is the same in both calls, so I don't understand why the second call to `insert` changes the size.

In my actual code, the insert call is protected by mutex and is called by a `std::thread`, the `thread` might call the `insert` function multiple times for the same position (first argument to `insert`), so I want to find a way to not increase the vector size and simply replace the value at the specified position.

Comment: For anyone downvoting, I'd appreciate greatly if you leave a quick comment why you did so, so that I can improve the question.

Comment: You've inserted the same number twice. How can you tell which position the second one is being inserted at?

Comment: How do you know that the insertion is happening in the wrong position? @BenjaminLindley: you were faster!

Comment: Method 2 and 1 dont do the same thing. Method two just sets .front() to 0 twice.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That is intentional. The size of the vector increases after the second insert. I see my question is wrong about the positions, I'll edit it now

Comment: @db7638: Yes, as it should. Because `insert` inserted another 0 into the vector, at the zeroth position. And the one that was formerly at the zeroth position is moved to the first position.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to insert new values at a specific location or substitute it at that location? Because insertion will increase the amount of values stored

Comment: Method 1 actually does do what you claim it doesn't.  If you are still having trouble with it, post a program that produces some output where the output is different to what you expected. [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I made some wrong conclusions earlier in my question but I've edited it and it's fixed now.

Comment: This is even more confusing since the edit. You can't say that you want to "insert, in other words, substitute". Insert and substitute are completely different operations. Inserting always increases the size of the vector.

Comment: @M.M Yes, it would be less confusing if there was a function called substitute for vectors. As far as I know, that doesn't exist. Feel free to edit the question

Comment: You've used `reserve` instead of `resize`. Your vector is ready to contain two elements, but still empty, hence the exception.

Comment: @db7638 nobody can tell what you are trying to ask -- it's up to you to be more clear.  The assignment operator performs the operation of "substitute".  The `insert` function performs the operation of "insert". If you want to insert and then substitute, you should call the `insert` function once and then use the assignment operator once.  Not call the insert function twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing two separate operations. Insertion of an element, and assignment to an element. Insertion creates a new element in the vector, increasing its size. Assignment changes the value of an element that's already there. Both of your calls to `insert` are in fact doing the same thing. They are inserting an element to the front position of your vector, and shifting all existing elements down by 1.

What you seem to be asking for is an operation that assigns to an element at a given index, but first inserts that element if it doesn't already exist. `std::vector` has no such operation, but you can write a function which allows you to do that.

```
template<typename T, typename A>
T& getElement(std::vector<T, A>& v, size_t N) {
    if (N >= v.size())
        v.resize(N + 1);
    return v[N];
}

// usage
getElement(vec, 4) = 7;
```

This has the side effect of inserting default constructed elements in any positions preceding that index which don't yet exist in the vector, which doesn't seem very desirable to me. Maybe you should consider using a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead. They have the exact behavior you are describing, but without inserting extra elements.

```
std::map<int, int> m;
m[0] = 0;
m[0] = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing out the initial inaccuracies in my question.